# Need software design advice on applying a multi-threaded approach for doing separated tasks with task-dependency awareness

Tags: multithreading, threadpool, software-design

Since I don't have much knowledge of multi-threaded design and English is not my native language, I don't know how to exactly describe my problem.
Let's say I have a mini-program in school, which has the responsibility to analyze a runtime feed. The feed is a continuous list of messages with the following format:

```
{"type": "A", "data": [...]} // message for doing task type A
{"type": "B", "data": [...]} // message for doing task type B
{"type": "C", "data": [...]} // message for doing task type C
...
```

For each message, I need to compute the corresponding task and then log the result to the `<task-type>.txt` file. Currently, my program synchronously does these tasks line by line.
However, the problem is:

- there are about 100 unique tasks (no data sharing) for 100 types, I believe it is a waste if not apply parallelism.
- for each type, the corresponding task requires the previous state. For example, given task type A which computes the `X` from `data` and `X(n-1)` from the last message if any, the flow is

```
message 1: {"type": "A", "data": [...]} --> compute X from data --> log X1 to file
message 2: {"type": "A", "data": [...]} --> compute X from data and X1 --> log X2 to file
message 3: {"type": "A", "data": [...]} --> compute X from data and X2 --> log X3 to file
```

In summary, my program should achieve the following requirements:

1. read the feed sequentially, parse each message, and assign the correct task for the `type` parsed from the message.
2. parallelizing the tasks with the awareness that if there is a **running task with the same type**, this new task needs to wait until the previous task is done.

I am stuck on the solution for step 2. I don't think creating a thread for each type is a good idea because I will make too much thread. So this leads me to a thread pool. But which kind of thread pool can meet the requirement mentioned in step 2?

Is there a generalized term for this problem that I can search for?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what do you mean by *runtime feed*, you said it's continous, but it have fixed size of 100x100. Do you read it at once, or do you read message by message?

Neverthless the first questions you should ask to yourself are:

- Why do you want to calculate tasks in parallel?
- Does task calculation takes longer than incoming message interval?
- Why do you want to optimize?

10k tasks is not much and I don't think you will get big gains here by applying multithreading.
Multithreaded code can be a pain to test, maintain and debug so use it with caution.

If you're still curious then you can open your programming language manual and read about:

- processing collections in parallel way - so you can read all messages, split them by *type* and process in parallel
- concurent queues - so you can create queue per *type* and process each queue in parallel but keeping the given *types* in sequence
- threads and threadpool (max size, limits, etc)